# How do I get git to stop "lying" to me about being up-to-date with a remote branch?

Tags: git

From my dev machine, I just pushed several new comments to the `origin/test` branch on my bitbucket account. Now I need to pull down that code to the deployment machine, so I checked out the `test` branch, like so:

```
$ git checkout test
```

I happened to already be on the test branch, so I got this message:

```
Already on 'test'
```

But I also got *this* message, which (on the surface) is very confusing:

```
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/test'.`
```

My branch is not, in fact, up-to-date with the version of `origin/test` that's on bitbucket. I just pushed new commits, after all!

I realize that I'm getting this message because my local copy of `test` is up-to-date with my *local* copy of `origin/test`, but I don't consider that information to be useful in this context, and it's very easy to misinterpret this message to mean that my local copy of `test` is to to date with the *remote* copy of `origin/test`, even though it's not.

Is it possible to simply silence this "Your branch is up-to-date" message? I never actually care, because of the way I use this deployment machine, so seeing it provides *only* confusion and frustration.

Comment: That is the whole point of Git being decentralized, your local copy of the origin state needs to be updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can condition yourself to `git fetch` often, to keep your `origin/*` in sync with the remote.

Edit:

Or you could create an alias to do a `fetch` before every `checkout`:

```
git config --global alias.fco '!git fetch && git checkout'
```

Comment: I was really hoping for a configuration option. I don't log in to this system to do *anything* except `git co <branch>` and then do a fabric deploy, so having to do an extra step eery time doesn't really work for me.

Comment: What would the option do, tho?  Force a "fetch" before "checkout"? You can always create a git alias to do that:  `git config --global alias.fco '!git fetch && git checkout'`.  Then you'd do `git fco <branch>`, and it'll do a fetch before the checkout, and you'll be told whether it's up to date with the remote.

Comment: If you have a little ritual you perform often, write a little script for it, make an alias for it, make a git alias for it.  This kind of thing is exactly what _shouldn't_ be built in to git.  Learn to use the tools you have and you'll never have to ask a question like this again.

Comment: That sounds like it'd actually be a really effective thing to do on that machine, but what's the exclamation point in that alias for?

Comment: Git aliases are normally git commands. A bang (`!`) at the beginning allows executing non-git commands.  I know "fetch" and "checkout" are git commands, but a regular alias only works for *one* command.  So you prefix with `!`, and then run regular shell commands.  In this case `git fetch && git checkout`.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the tracking information for your branch, then git status wouldn't show anything about being up to date or ahead.  You'd have to manually specify refs to fetch and push though.

Comment: I'd never considered that option, but not being shown a mildly misleading message isn't worth having to put in additional effort every time I use this box.